# Why is pg_wal filling up?

Tags: postgresql

We have a primary and standby PostgreSQL v14 server setup with streaming replication using:

```
pg_basebackup -h primary-server -U repuser --checkpoint=fast -D /data/db/postgresql/14/main/ -R --slot=foo -C --port=5432
```

We have not changed any settings in `postgresql.conf` except `listen_addresses`.

The streaming replication is working, all data is immediately available on the standby but the primary server is filling up it's `pg_wal/` directory non-stop until the disk is full and the server crashes.

It is my understanding that streaming replication does not work by the standby reading these "WAL" files in `pg_wal/` and that `pg_wal/` should only contain data not yet synched. IMHO this directory should automatically empty when all replicas are in synch.

As I mentioned no default settings were changed: `archive_mode` and `archive_command` are commented out.

1. Does streaming replication depend on this `pg_wal/` directory?
2. What is the correct process for preventing unfettered growth of `pg_wal/`?
3. Can I just switch `archive_mode` to off?

`select * from pg_replication_slots;` on the primary shows the slot `foo` of type `physical` and state `reserved`

4. What does the slot `foo` do and can I delete it?

UPDATE: The slot foo is active and cannot be deleted.

Comment: "Can I just switch archive_mode to off?"  It is off by default.  If you can find some place where it has been switched on, then switch it back off.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure

```
primary_slot_name = 'foo'
```

on the standby server, otherwise it will not use the replication slot, and the primary will keep the WAL indefinitely.

Comment: OK, this is weird - I havent configured `primary_slot_name` on the standby - it's commented out - but suddenly the pg_wal/ directory is NOT filling up.
What is also weird is that `primary_slot_name` is not mentioned in any guide on streaming replication.

Comment: Also, your explanation implies that the standby would not "use" the slot - but replication is working fine. Could it be that when I ran `pg_basebackup ` and provided a slot name that it is persisted somewhere else? It's not in postgresql.conf.

Comment: A replication slot is not necessary for replication. It is necessary for the primary to remember how much WAL it must retain in case the standby disconnects. As soon as you set `primary_slot_name`, the standby will make the primary move the slot ahead, so WAL on the primary can be removed.

Comment: OK, thank-you for the explanation. I guess the mystery now is: why is my primary server now clearing `pg_wal/` nicely without a configured `primary_slot_name` on the standby?

Comment: Either you dropped the replication slot, or something moved it ahead, or you have reached `max_slot_wal_keep_size`.

Comment: Must be "something" then because I have not changed `max_slot_wal_keep_size` and I could not delete the slot. I have a bad feeling that this problem resolved itself but could reappear again. Can I set `max_slot_wal_keep_size` to `1000000000` (1Gb) to avoid disk overflow in the future?

Comment: Could it be that `pg_wal/` overflowed because the standby disconnected for several days?

Comment: Yes, but only if a replication slot is in use.